# Fridge thermostat replacement - resealing?

Tags: thermostat, refrigerator

The thermostat on my drinks fridge is on the fritz, and I'd like to replace it. I've found a suitable replacement part; it's a WPF14B-EX.

To replace the thermostat, I need to withdraw the probe and wire from inside the body of the fridge and re-insert the replacement. Currently, this goes through some expanded foam insulation, along with the coolant pipe.

When I replace the probe, how do I ensure that I've adequately repaired the insulation/sealant?

Answer (score 1):

Is the current wiring sealed in some way?

If not, you have nothing to worry about, simply pull the wires, connect and go.

If so, replicate that sealing method. It's likely that there's a foam or rubber grommet of some sort, and it's likely that the replacement thermostat will come with one. If it doesn't come with it, order a replacement from the same place you've ordered the thermostat.

Comment: Not the wiring. The probe (the coiled bit in the pictures of the device) extends from the thermostat through into the inside of the cold compartment. On any normal fridge, yeah, it'd go through a grommet. On this fridge, it seems to go through a chunk of expanding foam. When I remove the existing probe, I'm likely to damage that in some way. I'm wondering whether I can just reseal it with -- literally -- expanding foam, or whether there's a special foam I need to use, or whether I just don't bother, 'cos the hole will be kinda small.

Comment: To clarify: I don't mean expanded foam, as in polystyrene. I literally mean the expanding gap-filling spray foam you get in a can. At least, that's what it looks like.

Comment: I can't imagine why expanding foam from a can _wouldn't_ work in this situation, even if the fridge's insulation is polystyrene. I'd have a can handy and _if_ you damage the existing foam, spray a bit in there to replace it. I'd use the "low expanding" stuff designed for window and door installation - you're _less likely_ to make a mess that way, but there's a significant chance you'll make a mess anyway.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms my guess. Do you know if there are any food-safety implications?

Comment: Once cured, I can't imagine that there would be any issues whatsoever. I wouldn't recommend spraying the foam on crackers and eating it like you would with "cheese" in a can...